# How to apply SwiftUI opacity to the parent View only?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Applying opacity to the View in SwiftUI passing it down through the hierarchy and looks like it works kinda Environment value. It causes the behaviour when each subview is being affected by opacity independently. No matter if we put the yellow circle with the overlay, background, or inside ZStack.

[image]

How can we make opacity affecting to the parent view only, like it behaves in UIKit, so the whole view with all its content will became translucent as a single solid object?

```
struct OpacityTest: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 30) {
            buttonContent
                .opacity(0.5)

            Button(action: {}) {
                buttonContent
            }
        }
    }
    
    var buttonContent: some View {
        Image(systemName: "calendar.circle")
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 65, height: 65)
            .overlay(
                Circle()
                    .fill(Color.yellow)
                    .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .topTrailing)
            )
    }
}

struct OpacityTest_Preview: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        OpacityTest()
    }
}
```

**Update:**
As ChrisR answered, .drawingGroup() does the job and partially solves the issue, but until everything is inside the parent view bounds. Once we add offset to the view inside overlay, it's being cropped. Any chance to avoid that?

```
.overlay(
    Circle()
        .fill(Color.yellow)
        .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
        .offset(x: 10, y: -10) //This modifier brakes the drawingGroup
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .topTrailing)
    )
```

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Adding `.compositingGroup()` does the job. It makes external modifiers work only on the top level and not being passed through hierarchy. Also does not crop any subviews with offset and keeps original frame for layout.

```
var buttonContent: some View {
    Image(systemName: "calendar.circle")
        .resizable()
        .frame(width: 65, height: 65)
        .overlay(
            Circle()
                .fill(Color.yellow)
                .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                .offset(x: 10, y: -10)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .topTrailing)
        )
        .compositingGroup() //here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add.`.drawingGroup()`. This will apply all further modifiers to the whole object/view:

```
    var buttonContent: some View {
        Image(systemName: "calendar.circle")
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 65, height: 65)
            .overlay(
                Circle()
                    .fill(Color.yellow)
                    .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .topTrailing)
            )
        .drawingGroup() // here
    }
```

**EDIT as to OPs Update:**

`.offset` does not change the size/bounds of the view but just shifts the rendering, which leads to unwanted clipping. You could go with `geometryReader` but in the example with fixed sizes it should be enough to enlarge the parent frame manually to avoid the clipping:

```
    var buttonContent: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .topTrailing) {
            Image(systemName: "calendar.circle")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 65, height: 65)
            Circle()
                .fill(Color.yellow)
                .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                .offset(x: 10, y: -10)
        }
        .frame(width: 95, height: 95) // here
        .drawingGroup()
    }
```

Comment: Yeeeeeah! Thank you Chris!

Comment: One more question — .drawingGroup() clips everything to the parent view bounds. Any chance to avoid that?

Comment: I've added explanation to the question and included the screenshot.

Comment: Thanks but that's not what I was looking for. I don't want to break layout, I need the main button to keep original size that works inside any complex layout. I've added the answer, .compositingGroup() does the job.

Comment: I did not copy it at all. I've used compositingGroup modifier. drawingGroup did not work as expected for the views outside the bounds. It was cropping them. 100% sure I've copied piece of code from my question and added the row with compositingGroup modifier.

Comment: ok. sorry. you're right.

Comment: But thanks anyways, I will know about drawingGroup now (did some research) that makes rendering with Metal and can dramatically improve performance if needed. I've also found compositingGroup by starting typing ".group" and found the compositingGroup modifier in code completion popup :)) So that's thanks to you))

Answer (score -1):

If we apply any modifier to parent View it also effect on child Views as well.

Remove `.opacity(0.5)` from **buttonContent** and add it before **.overlay** modifier

Comment: Did you try it before answering? 1. It does not affect overlay at all like that (tried just now). 2. It will not work for the button even if it would.